# Authorize.net CIM API Duplicate transactions

Tags: xml, api, authorize.net

Any help here would be appreciated.

As of 3 days ago our website began randomly authorizing transactions twice on authorize.net CIM transactions with the exact same details.  Since this came out of the blue without any changes on our end, I am trying to set duplicateWindow or x_duplicate_window to stop the second transaction since I don't know where it is coming from (it seems to have no pattern as to when it happens).

Below is an example of the xml that is being sent that doesnt seem to work.  Again, any help would be appreciated.

```
<createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
<merchantAuthentication>
    <name>ACCOUNT_ID</name>
    <transactionKey>TRANS_KEY</transactionKey>
</merchantAuthentication>
<refId></refId>
<transaction>
    <profileTransAuthOnly>
        <amount>5.97</amount>
        <customerProfileId>CUST_PROFILE</customerProfileId>
        <customerPaymentProfileId>PAY_PROFILE</customerPaymentProfileId>
        <order>
            <invoiceNumber>4032486</invoiceNumber>
            <description></description>
            <purchaseOrderNumber></purchaseOrderNumber>
        </order>
    </profileTransAuthOnly>
</transaction>
<extraOptions><![CDATA[x_duplicate_window=10]]></extraOptions>
</createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to confirm here that you're not insane. We were seeing random duplicate transactions generated in our production authorize.net account from two batches that were created on Jan 12 and Jan 19, within a second of each other as logged in the account. I spent my entire afternoon yesterday trying to get it figured out (downstream proxy replaying POST, etc). Turned out the exact same XML (switching identifiers) would trigger a duplicate transaction error against the test API endpoint, but no error would get generated in production. Seemed to be no way to get a duplicate transaction error in production.

After being on the phone with their folks for a while, I put together a volume of info on this to send to the developers. I pushed another test to production just for fun, and got the duplicate transaction error back. I don't know if it ended up being something on their side, or something with the account, but it started working "correctly" around 11am CST on Jan 20th, 2016. I still sent that info to the devs and will hopefully see some more info on this, but you should see if it's now no longer a problem for you.